# Why do lower case and uppercase letters have the same Java Character getNumericValue() value?

Tags: java, character

Why does getNumericValue('a') and getNumericValue('A') both return 10 when they're technically different characters?

Comment: Well, they're the same when interpreted in hex, which is basically what `getNumericValue` is doing...  (Basically: reread the docs.)

Comment: [Base 36, actually](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char))

Answer (score 6):

## Read the doc

Programming by intuition is risky business. Best to read the documentation before typing the code.

As explained in the Javadoc, [`Character.getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) parses the character as a digit or some other numerical representation. The Javadoc explicitly says that a-z and A-Z produce numbers in range of 10-35.

You can configure your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) to automatically display the Javadoc for the code in your code editor.

## Code point

Apparently you want the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number for a particular character.

```
int codePoint_a = Character.codePointAt( "a" , 0 ) ;  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
int codePoint_A = Character.codePointAt( "A" , 0 ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/xoUtjr).

> codePoint_a = 97
>
> codePoint_A = 65

## Avoid legacy `char`

Best to avoid `char`. As a 16-bit value, the `char` type is physically incapable of representing most characters. The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2.

Consider `char` to be a legacy type, generally supplanted by code point integer numbers. You will find `codePoint` methods on classes such as `String`, `StringBuilder`, `Character`, etc.